# A sequence {$x_n$} converges to $y$ in the upper-limit topology iff it converges to $y$ from above in the usual topology.

Tags: general-topology

Prove that a sequence {$x_n$} converges to $y$ in the upper-limit topology iff it converges to $y$ from above (or from the right) in the usual topology.

---

can somebody help me please to solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. However, it becomes true if you replace *upper-limit topology* by [*lower-limit topology*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorgenfrey_line), and I’ll make that change.

Suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ in the lower-limit topology. That means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in[x,x+\epsilon)$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. (Why?) From this you should have no trouble concluding that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ from above in the usual topology.

Now suppose that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ from the right in the usual topology. Explain why that means that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n\in[x,x+\epsilon)$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$, and you’ll have shown that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $x$ in the lower-limit topology.

---

The intuitive point here is that if $U$ is a basic open neighborhood of $x$ in one of these two topologies, and you’re looking only at the part of $U$ to the right of $x$, you can’t tell whether $U$ is a Euclidean open set of the form $(a,b)$ for some $a$ and $b$ with $a<x<b$, or whether $U$ is a lower-limit-topology open set of the form $[x,b)$ for some $b>x$.